# Encoding emoji r

Tags: r, emoji

I loaded a database on R. I have to carry out a sentiment analysis. I tried encoding emoji with the `iconv` command, but then if I go to analyze a message with emoji inside it gives me the value NA.

For example in message 4 you can see a blue heart
[image: message 4 with emoji blue heart]

Later I performed the following actions for emoji encoding

```
texts = posts$message
texts <- iconv(texts, 'UTF-8', 'ASCII')
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(texts))
```

but then if I go to analyze message 4 via function `inspect(corpus[4])` it gives me the NA value, instead of showing me the message.

if I run the command `dput(data[1:7,])`  i get this

```
structure(list(created_time = structure(c(1500042659, 1500042059, 
1500039638, 1500036945, 1500036300, 1500033950, 1500031022), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), description = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    link = c("https://www.facebook.com/bbcnews/videos/10154890879532217/", 
    "http://bbc.in/2talMsx", "https://www.facebook.com/bbcnews/videos/10154890852247217/", 
    "https://www.facebook.com/bbcnews/videos/1426789250735491/", 
    "https://www.facebook.com/bbcnews/videos/10154890645702217/", 
    "http://bbc.in/2upZBP3", "http://bbc.in/2uqthLM"), message = c("We are #LIVE outside the National Rifle Association of America's headquarters for a demonstration organised by the Women's March. The BBC's Hetal Gandhi is speaking to NRA supporters and activists from the Women's March about the recent verdict in #PhilandoCastile's death and a controversial NRA commercial - that sparked this event. Share your questions below.", 
    "UPDATE: \r\n-2 Ukrainian tourists killed in stabbing at hotel in Red Sea resort of Hurghada in Egypt. \r\n-Four others wounded. \r\n-Suspect arrested, officials say.", 
    "Proms: Come with us on a tour of the Royal Albert Hall as preparations are underway for the biggest classical music festival in the world - the Proms. Check out https://www.bbc.co.uk/proms for the full schedule of events.", 
    "Thousands say their final goodbyes to Bradley Lowery http://bbc.in/2ugAwWm <U+0001F499>\r\n\r\n(Via BBC Look North (North East & Cumbria))", 
    "Despite safety warnings, this beach near an airport has become a world-famous attraction. Tourists get up close to planes, with sometimes devastating consequences. bbc.in/2sSscbj", 
    "\"Grandparents are the epitome of close family members\" - a judge in Hawaii has dealt another blow to Donald J. Trump's travel ban.", 
    "Thousands have come to say goodbye to Bradley Lowery, the six-year-old Sunderland AFC fan who died from cancer, police say."
    ), page_id = c(228735667216, 228735667216, 228735667216, 
    228735667216, 228735667216, 228735667216, 228735667216), 
    post_id = c("228735667216_10154890879532217", "228735667216_10154890968202217", 
    "228735667216_10154890852247217", "228735667216_1426789250735491", 
    "228735667216_10154890645702217", "228735667216_10154890600247217", 
    "228735667216_10154890480662217"), react_angry = c(54, 172, 
    5, 6, 65, 25, 0), react_haha = c(24, 8, 12, 0, 513, 136, 
    2), react_like = c(993, 994, 2034, 2262, 4336, 2549, 4123
    ), react_love = c(144, 11, 369, 754, 54, 195, 1005), react_sad = c(12, 
    783, 6, 1989, 128, 2, 2256), react_wow = c(24, 264, 45, 11, 
    815, 17, 41), scrape_time = structure(c(1500030084.37986, 
    1500030084.37986, 1500030084.37986, 1500030084.37986, 1500030084.37986, 
    1500030084.37986, 1500030084.37986), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), shares = c(139, 680, 395, 542, 1956, 159, 560
    )), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: I did, see if it's okay

Comment: First, you should use `inspect(corpus[[4]])` instead of `inspect(corpus[4])`

Comment: Always gives me NA, even with your command

Comment: Please, could you try the code given at this link? https://pastebin.com/MrZnN8nn  Let me know what you get.

Comment: I did, see if it's okay

Comment: You should get the content of message 4 with a unicode symbol inside.